# how to create Product Catalog Batch , ecommerce on facebook business sdk php

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

i use facebook business sdk 11.0
for create new product category ecommerce

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk

I tried to read document but I still can't understand it.

try but show error
(#100) The parameter requests is required

```
$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
        $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

        $fields = array(
        );
        $params = array(
            'retailer_id' => 'retailer-6',
            "availability" => "in stock",
            "brand" => "Nike",
            "category" => "t-shirts",
            "description" => "product description",
            "image_url" => "http://www.images.example.com/t-shirts/1.png",
            "name" => "product name",
            "price" => "10.00",
            "currency" => "USD",
            "condition" => "new",
            "url" => "http://www.images.example.com/t-shirts/1.png",
            "retailer_product_group_id" => "product-group-1"
        );
        echo json_encode((new ProductCatalog($id))->createBatch(
            $fields,
            $params
        )->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to doesn't even appear to mention creating product catalogs. You should probably start by reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/batch/

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/ProductCatalogHotelsPost.php this example i can create product hotel and create catalogs but no example for catalog ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

```
$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
        $api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

        $fields = array(
        );
        $data[] = array(
            'method'=>'CREATE',
            'retailer_id'=>'retailer-6',
            'data'=>array(
                "availability" => "in stock",
                "brand" => "Nike",
                "category" => "t-shirts",
                "description" => "product description",
                "image_url" => "http://www.images.example.com/t-shirts/1.png",
                "name" => "product name",
                "price" => "1000", //it will be 1000 otherwise it will through error
                "currency" => "INR",
                "condition" => "new",
                "url" => "http://www.images.example.com/t-shirts/1.png",
                "retailer_product_group_id" => "product-group-1"
            )
        );
        
        $params = array(
            'access_token'=>$access_token,
            'requests'=>$data
        );
        echo json_encode((new ProductCatalog($product_catalog_id))->createBatch(
            $fields,
            $params
        )->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


Try this one it will work.
```